# Drawing in UIView on touch points gives blurr drawing effect on boundaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, core-graphics, calayer

To sort out my last problem : [Draw/Paint like sketch color inside a bezier path in UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658974/draw-paint-like-sketch-color-inside-a-bezier-path-in-uiview), I took an exact Image (of path) filled with selected color. Then, to draw that in `UIView`, for context color I took:

```
lineColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:img];
```

in drawrect :

```
CGPoint mid1 = midPoint(previousPoint1, previousPoint2);
CGPoint mid2 = midPoint(currentPoint, previousPoint1);
[curImage drawInRect:CGRectZero];
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[self.layer renderInContext:context];
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mid1.x, mid1.y);
CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, 
                             previousPoint1.x, 
                             previousPoint1.y, 
                             mid2.x, 
                             mid2.y);
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeCopy);
CGContextSetLineJoin(context, kCGLineJoinRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,lineColor.CGColor);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, YES);
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, YES);
CGContextSetFlatness(context,0.5);
CGContextSetAlpha(context, 1.0);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

It draws exactly in the path of view but on boundaries the color goes out like melting effect.

Source Image in which color has to be filled :
[image: Image to be filled with color]

image to be used as colorWithPatternImage (img)[image]

After drawing on touches ,resultimg Image :
[image]

What am I missing here to fill it perfectly?
Any help with core graphics is most welcomed!
Thank You!

To mask the image I also did :

```
-(void)clipView :(MyUIBezierPath*)path drawingView:(DrawingView*)myView
{
    MyUIBezierPath *myClippingPath =path;
    CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    mask.path = myClippingPath.CGPath;
    myView.layer.mask = mask;
}
```

But colorWithPatternImage and this masking does the same trick i.e lets me draw only inside the path , the problem I am facing now is : It gives a bad effect on drawing on touch points around the boundaries of path !

Comment: Should you not be applying a clipping mask to the layer, so you only see it draw inside the bezier. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20410146/use-bezier-path-as-clipping-mask

Comment: I tried it all ready.Its the same issue with this , the color around boundary still feels like flowing , not outside though , from inside it flows away from boundary of path.Problem is with draw at touch points , masking isn't the issue.

Comment: Is it the same with anti-alias off?

Comment: Yes I tried :  CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, NO);
      CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, NO); but this also doesnt help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well its working with my own masking method via colorWithPatternImage , though masking it by clipping is the same thing.Drawing issue was because of the image being drawn at touch point in the method "calculateMinImageArea: CGPoint1 :CGPoint2 :CGPoint3". Changing its dimensions (height-width according to line width) sorts it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a path points out of this image. Then make a `CGPathRef` or `CGMutablePathRef` and then use it as a mask to your `CGContextRef`.

Comment: Create a path out of which image ?

Comment: source image which you've posted first.

Comment: I already have the path stored and with that only I am getting the second Image.The concern is on continously calling touches moved around boundaries , the color start flowing out. See my linked question to see how I am drawing it in drawRect.

Comment: if you have the path, then you can try masking as in my answer above.

Comment: As I mentioned , masking isnt the issue now , masking it this way or getitng an image and doing colorwithpatternimage does the same task , the issue is with the draw technique ! inside the path it works fine but on the boundaries , while moving the touch , it gives a effect like color is flowing as you can see in the last image !