# iOS - How to draw lines in irregular areas

Tags: ios, draw

I want my brush to draw in this 'V', not beyond 'V'.

Is there any implementation idea or solution? Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: Look at these links 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709045/drawing-in-uiview-on-touch-points-gives-blurr-drawing-effect-on-boundaries . 2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50944736/how-to-draw-inside-the-black-edges-in-ios-sdk-with-opengl-es . 3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30658974/draw-paint-like-sketch-color-inside-a-bezier-path-in-uiview

Comment: hi，Gagan. Tank you for your help.